# How to iterate over a list of variable names in PHP

Tags: php

The input record includes fifteen fields named 'student01', 'student02', student03' ... 'student15'. I need to do the same thing with the value stored in each of the fields. There's got to be a better way than:

```php
if ($student01 != '') {
// process the info in $student01
}
if ($student02 != '') {
// process the info in $student02
}
...
if ($student15 != '') {
// process the info in $student15
}
```

I was thinking that PHP's variable variables might be the solution, but haven't figured out the right syntax.

Help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: are the condition bodies the same?

Comment: Can you show how you declare $student01 to $student15?

Comment: Put all the items into an array and then loop through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the number 3 in the for statement to be 1 more than the number of students you are going to have.

```
for ($snum = 1;$snum < 3;$snum++) {

    #echo ${'student' . str_pad($snum,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)}; // left to show it works
    if (${'student' . str_pad($snum,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)} != '') {
       echo 'Do something';
    }

}
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!